# How to Escape Curly Braces in MS-SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a string in MS-SQL DB as

```
%{AAAAA-4126-BBBB-a1ee-XXXXXXXX}="CN={ABCDEE-7234-GTEF-93CB-53889EFIGJ},CN=Pol,CN=SYS,DC=Company,DC=XXX,DC=org"
```

I'd like to cut pattern `ABCDEE-7234-GTEF-93CB-53889EFIGJ` from string in MS-SQL 2012.

Comment: Does `%{AAAAA-4126-BBBB-a1ee-XXXXXXXX}` belong to your string? If so, is this how your string pattern looks like?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly string looks like. I have tried select Right(<col name> ,CHARINDEX('CN={', <col name>)). But, getting o/p as Pol,CN=SYS,DC=Company,DC=XXX,DC=org. Not able to figure out how to get proper right string. So, that I will again cut it using LEFT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(<col name>, CHARINDEX('CN={', <col name>) + 4, 32)
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Yes, it works. Just modified your answer and used :: SUBSTRING( <col name>, CHARINDEX('CN=', <col name>) +3,( CHARINDEX(',CN', <col name>) -CHARINDEX('CN=',<col name>) -3))